# Windows 10 - Adding application to left navigation pane

Tags: windows, registry

I have an application which when I install in Windows 10, need to show up in left navigation pane. Now, I checked how other applications like OneDrive, DropBox which when installed in Windows 10, show up in the navigation pane. Apparently, it was mentioned that there is a DWORD value in registry which controls this behavior which is System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree. This value should be set to 1. But, when I tried to create this value in registry manually for my application's registry entries, it did not work for me. I am kind of stuck here. So, can somebody please help me in this regard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of search and studying Dropbox entries in the Windows registry, I figured out the answer. We have to create new keys and sub keys with the following values similar to this GUID {E31EA727-12ED-4702-820C-4B6445F28E1A}:

1. Create a new GUID for the application online.
2. Search for the Dropbox GUID as mentioned above and add keys/subkeys similar to Dropbox.

After putting entries similar to Dropbox into Windows registry, I am able to see my application in the left navigation pane :-)

However, there is still one issue with this change. After changing the registry entries, a folder in Desktop got created with the name of my application and there is not even a delete option on it, somewhat like Recycle Bin. Any idea how to fix this issue ?

Comment: I figured out the answer for the last blocker too :-) You need to add an entry for the application with a value of 1 at the below location - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to create guid for the application online?

Comment: You can go to this site https://www.guidgenerator.com/ and click on "Generate some GUID's".

Comment: Creating a Guid is pretty simple yet my focus is how is the Guid connected to the to your application?, by looking at the entries, i didn't found a path to the application, or any other path to be quite honest...

Comment: To connect the GUID with your application you have to add entries into the registry. You can check how other applications like Dropbox binds their GUID's in the registry, it is fairly simple. For eg - one of the entry "TargetFolderPath" points to the actual Dropbox share folder path.